# Контекстные фильтры - views - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, views

Помогите, нужно сделать такую функциональность:
Идет вывод терминов таксономии в блоке(с помощью views) , нужно сделать так что бы при появлении в url someurl/NID вывести термины которые принадлежат этому материалу.
По отдельные смог сделать(два блока, один - все термины, другой - при выборе определенного материала).
Другой пример - taxonomy/term/4 - выводит все данные по этому термину, а taxonomy/term/4/nid выводит все материалы, которые принадлежат этому термину и материалу(материалы соединяются с помощью node reference

Comment: Очень много информации по таким фильтрам
[вот здесь][1] посмотрите

[1]: http://gavzav.ru/blog/5-kontekstnye-filtry-otnosheniya-i-td

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет!
Посмотрите здесь: http://xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/553 
http://xandeadx.ru/blog/drupal/234

вообще сайт mast have )